# Install luarocks-3.8.0 on windows-latest github workflow runner with custom lua intepreter luajit-2.0.4

Tags: lua, github-actions, luarocks, github-actions-runners

I am trying to install luarocks-3.8.0 on githubs workflow runner using windows-stable, but unfortunatelly I am not able to set any [arguments](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-Windows) with success.

I tried the following:

- without any argument
- with and without /P
- with and without /LUA
- with and without /INC
- with and without /LIB
- with and without /BIN

One of the Powershell commands I used, see below:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "${{ github.workspace }}\luarocks-3.8.0-win32\luarocks-3.8.0-win32\install.bat" -ArgumentList "/FORCECONFIG" -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

As you can see I also tried to provide a config.lua by using /FORCECONFIG and copying the config file from ${{ github.workspace }}\luarocks-3.8.0\config-windows.5.1.lua to C:\luarocks\config.lua,

but I always get this error:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

I tried --verbose without success.

Additional info:

- I am using luaJIT-2.0.4 and installed it on the workflow runner
- I need luarocks to install luaunit for unit testing
- inside of directory [.building](https://github.com/Ismoh/NoitaMP/tree/unit-tests/.building) you can see all provided files
- Workflow action can be found [here](https://github.com/Ismoh/NoitaMP/actions/workflows/windows-latest-lua-unit-testing.yml)
- and the workflow action yml [file](https://github.com/Ismoh/NoitaMP/actions/runs/1607206290/workflow#L46) "Windows Lua Unit Testing" - see step "Install luarocks 3.8.0"

If you need any additional information, please let me know!
I am getting out of ideas how to solve this!

A verbose output with install.bat would really help me out, but it doesn't seems to be working and I am unable to find anything about verbose output on windows with install.bat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I used the already builded version of luarocks (luarocks.exe) https://luarocks.org/releases/luarocks-3.8.0-windows-32.zip

After that I simply use luarocks.exe install luacov --tree /path/to/lua. Lib, dir, include and share will be added by luarocks. After that I was able to use luacov with luajit, because I set the luajit path inside the tree command.